# Postgres convert from bytea which contains float (IEEE 754) to real (float4)

Tags: postgresql

The following SQL SELECT query returns an integer:

```
SELECT (((get_byte(dalsk.data, 0)::bit(8)) || 
    (get_byte(dalsk.data, 1)::bit(8)) ||
    (get_byte(dalsk.data, 2)::bit(8)) ||
    get_byte(dalsk.data, 3)::bit(8)) :: bit(32)) :: integer --AS rezult_float
FROM (SELECT substring(data from 2 for 5) AS data FROM raw_data WHERE 
    raw_data_id = 33) 
AS dalsk;
```

Whenever I try to cast the result from integer to real, I get the following error:

> Cannot cast type bit to real.

Is there a way to convert the value to float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IEEE754 doesn't cover endianess so that's not enough info to convert the binary to float. If you want to convert it you will have to create a function or a [cast operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html).